# PHP : Read a single table from multiple tables

Tags: php, html

I am creating a project where I want to read a single HTML table where there are 3 HTML tables and print it's contents. How can I do that? As you can see from the code below, I want to get the elements from ROW element of the below mentioned table. But after this table, there are 2 more tables, for which I don't want the information. WHen I run the PHP code, I can see the information from all the 3 tables. Thank you.

```
<p>
    <div class="name-block" style="margin-left:200px; margin-top: 35px;">
        <h4 style="border: 1px solid black; display: inline;">TIM - Web Server Setup</h4>
    </div>
        <table id="webserver" align="center" class="table-block">
            <tr class="highlight">
                <td width="100"><div>IP address</div></td>
                <td width="900" contenteditable='true'>TEST</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="highlight">
                <td width="100"><div>Netmask</div></td>
                <td width="900" contenteditable='true'>TEST</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="highlight">
                <td width="100"><div>Gateway</div></td>
                <td width="900" contenteditable='true'></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="highlight">
                <td width="100"><div>User</div></td>
                <td width="900" contenteditable='true'><div width="900" contenteditable></td></div>
            </tr>

            <tr class="highlight">
                <td width="100"><div>Password</div></td>
                <td width="900" contenteditable='true'><div width="900" contenteditable></td></div>
            </tr>

            <tr class="highlight">
                <td width="100"><div>Port</div></td>
                <td width="900" contenteditable='true'><div width="900" contenteditable></td></div>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </p>

       <p><input type="button" id="bt" value="Show Table Data"" /></p>

<?php

$data = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/page.php');

$doc = new domDocument;

@$doc->loadHTML($data);
 $i=0;
    while(is_object($finance = $doc->getElementsById("table")->item($i)))
       {
        foreach($finance->childNodes as $nodename)
          {
            if($nodename->nodeName=='tr')
              {
               foreach($nodename->childNodes as $subNodes)
                {
                 echo $subNodes->nodeName." - ".$subNodes->nodeValue."<br>";
               }
           }
           else
             {
              echo $nodename->nodeName." - ".$nodename->nodeValue."<br>";
             }
         }
      $i++;
    }
?>
//Other 2 tables below
```

Comment: Your table has an id, but it is "webserver" not "table". Id's, being unique, are there to enable a specific element to be targetted.

Comment: @AndyG : That's the ID I have given to try to get elements by ID, but it doesn't work.  I get Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementsById(). As soon as I change that to table, it works.

Comment: **getElementById** not ..Elements..

Comment: share the '/var/www/html/page.php' file to make it work

Comment: @AndyG :  PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DOMElement::item()

Comment: @asimshahiddIT : The added file in question is page.php. I have ommited the 2 tables I don't require.

Comment: @WeareBorg So what is that error telling you? It seems that it now recognises a DOMElement, but such does not have an item() method. Please attempt to interpret error message(s).

Comment: @AndyG : I changed it to getAttribute, and now I don't see any table data. Any idea what I might be doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Put another way, a single DOMElement, which getElementById returns, does not have an items collection. It will have child nodes though, so you can probably just omit the call of item().

Comment: @AndyG : Tried that as well, the whole web page slows down and I get a 30 seconds timeout error for a simple page.

Comment: @WeareBorg I just saw your comment above, why did you change to getAttribute? What attribute are you trying to get?

Comment: @AndyG : Let's try in chat? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188211/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-andy-g).

Comment: @WeareBorg No thanks. getElementById gives a single element, so you don't need the while loop. You then navigate its children. Check the correct use of methods, and correct any ensuing errors. Good luck. Your original question has been answered, which is to use an id to target a specific table/element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table you wish to reference has an ID, use this ID with `getElementById` to target this specific table/element.

`getElementById` returns a single element, so the while loop is no longer relevant.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I assigned for each TD element an ID, and got individual ones by ID and then processed them.